# How can I compare a regex object as if I would been using flex, in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code, what I'am trying to do is that when it receives the input from text_to_search, it finds if it is an instruction, it is any word that is not an instruction (ID) or it is an operator, so far it prints me if it founds an instruction but in the ID part it also prints me Set, instead of for example jaja, so how can I achieve this?

```
text_to_search="Set Sets UnionShowSets jaja:={hi};"
import re
      t=re.search(r'Sets?|ShowSet|ShowSets|Union|Intersect|SetUnion|SetIntersect',text_to_search)
    s=re.search(r':=|{|}|;',text_to_search)
    d=t=re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+',text_to_search)
    if t:
        print("Instruction: ")
        print(t)
    else:
        print("ID: ")
        print(d)

    if s:
        print("Operator: ")
        print(s)
```

Print result:

```
Instruction: 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Set'>
Operator: 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(27, 29), match=':='>
```

Desired print result:

```
Instruction: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Set'>
Instruction: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Sets'>
Instruction: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Union'>
Instruction: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='ShowSets'>
ID: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='jaja'>
ID: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='hi'>
Operator: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='{'>
Operator: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='}'>
Operator: 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(27, 29), match=':='>
Operator: 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(27, 29), match=';'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it just by saving in a list the elements I didnt want to print again:

```
text_to_search="Set Sets UnionShowSets jaja:={hola};"
import re
x=[]

for match in re.finditer('Sets?|ShowSet|ShowSets|Union|Intersect|SetUnion|SetIntersect',text_to_search):
    print("Instruccion: ")
    print(match)
    x.append(match)
for match in re.finditer(r':=|{|}|;',text_to_search):
    print("Operador: ")
    print(match)
for match in re.finditer(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+',text_to_search):
    if match in x:
        continue
    else:
        print("ID: ")
        print(match)
```